# Deriving the Majorana equations of motion from a Lagrangian density

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-principle, variational-calculus, majorana-fermions

This is regarding exercise 3.4b in Peskin and Schroeder's *Introduction to Quantum Field Theory*. This problem asks us to find the equations of motion for the Majorana field (the equations of motion were given in part a to be $i\bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \chi - im \sigma^2 \chi^* = 0$). The action is given by $S* = \int d^4x L$, where $L = $ Lagrangian density $= \chi^\dagger i \bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \chi + \frac{im}{2}\bigg(\chi^T \sigma^2 \chi - \chi^\dagger \sigma^2 \chi^* \bigg)$.

To find the equations of motion I decided to use $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \chi^\dagger} = \partial_\mu \bigg(\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\mu \chi^\dagger)} \bigg)$ and got $i\bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \chi - \frac{im}{2}\sigma^2 \chi^* = 0$.

The solution's manual said to vary $S$ and I think that I did that (the euler lagrange equations are derived from varying S and L)

**What did I do incorrectly? What would be the correct way to find the equations of motion?**

Comment: Is the problem in the fact that you used the Euler Lagrange equations instead of varying $S$? Or did you get the wrong answer? Because the Euler Lagrange equations are basically a fast way to vary the action.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion I got the wrong answer but I think I figured out what is wrong (I will post answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not really a standard notion of an operation that takes $\xi\to \xi^*$ for a Grassmann variable and in a Euclidean signature Grassmann path integral $\psi$ and $\psi^*$ are independent objects. I don't know how widespread P&S's $(ab)^*=-b^*a^*$ is but I find it confusing.  Also  appearences of $i\sigma_2$ as in P&S are dependent on the choice of representation for the Gamma matrices.

I think is much simpler just to take
the  Grassmann-variable Majorana action  to be
$$
S_{\rm Majorana} ={\textstyle \frac 12} \int \psi^T C (\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu +m)\psi\, d^4x 
$$
where $C$ is the charge conjugation matrix defined by $C\gamma^\mu C^{-1}= -(\gamma^\mu)^T$. (Peter van Nieuwenhuizen calls $\psi^T C$ the Majorana adjoint, and his discussion seems simpler than P&S.)

In 4 Euclidean dimensions the  expression $C (\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu +m)$ is skew symmetric in the combined spin and $x$ space, so just as the "variation" of
the quadratic Grassmann expression
$$
S={\textstyle \frac 12} \xi^TA\xi
$$
with $A$ a skew-symmetric matrix gives $A\xi=0$,
the variation of  gives the equation of motion
$$
(\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu +m)\psi=0.
$$

In Minkowski signature the four-component spinor is no longer  a Grassman variable but is  operator-valued with $\bar\psi= \psi^\dagger \gamma^0$ with $\dagger$ implying the adjoint operation on the many-body Hilbert space as usual. The field $\psi$  however, satisfies the Majorana condition
$$
\psi=\psi^c\equiv  C^{-1} \bar\psi^T
$$
and the anticommutation commutation relations
$$
\{\psi_\alpha(x), \psi_\beta(x')\}_{t=t'} = [\gamma^0 C^{-1}]_{\alpha\beta} \delta^3(x-x').
$$
In the space-time dimensions ($d=2,3,4$ mod 8) where Majorana's exist the matrix $\gamma^0 C^{-1}$ is symmetric --- as it needs to be for the anticommutator  to be consistent with the RHS.

I think that in the $\gamma^5$ diagonal representation of the Gamma matrices we have
$$
C= \left[\matrix{0& i \sigma_2\\ -i\sigma_2&0}\right],
$$
so it should be possible to match my basis-independent notation to that of P&S.

Answer (score 0):

$\chi^T \sigma^2 \chi = (-\chi^* \sigma^2 \chi^\dagger)^*$ and then differentiate to get another $-\frac{im}{2}\sigma^2 \chi^*$

Note that the values $\chi$ takes are Grassmann numbers and so, as noted in the exercise description, $(\alpha \beta)^* = - \alpha^* \beta^*$.

Thus: $\chi^T \sigma^2 \chi = (-\chi^* \sigma^2 \chi^\dagger)^* = (\chi^*)^*(\sigma^2 \chi^\dagger)^* = -(\chi^*)^*(\chi^\dagger)^*\sigma^2 = (\sigma^2\chi^\dagger \chi^*)^*$